# using modulus to find out if number is divisible by variable not working

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with using the % operator. This is hard to explain, so I'll just show my code first.

```
#include <windows.h>
const char ClassName[] = "WindowClass";
int divisible = 1;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 50, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if (divisible % 15 == 0) {
            MessageBox(hwnd, "a", "a", MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE | MB_ICONASTERISK);
        }
        divisible++;
        break;
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD);

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        ClassName,
        "Tank Survival",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 820, 642,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

So what happens is that the messagebox in WM_TIMER repeats every time WM_TIMER is called although it should only run every 15 times WM_TIMER is called.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: *messagebox in WM_TIMER repeats every time WM_TIMER is called* - why you decide this ?

Comment: Why don't you put the value of divisible in the message box so you can see what the actual value is... or maybe put a breakpoint inside the if(d%15) block

Comment: and instead *MessageBox* here (this is affect message processing) use *DbgPrint* or *OutputDebugString*

Comment: The message box will display roughly every 750 ms. How did you determine, that it is being displayed when it shouldn't have been?

Comment: @IInspectable i tried changing 15 to 50 and the same problem occurs (i think i know the difference between 50ms and 2500ms)

Comment: btw im a beginner, my code is very bad. doing c++ just for fun. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some good points have been made in the comments, but the essential problem here is that Windows continues to dispatch messages (including WM_TIMER messages) while the message box is on the screen so you end up recursively calling `MessageBox` each time the timer fires (but, since these are all on top of one another, you only see the one).

One way to resolve this is to kill the timer while the message box is on the screen, like so:

```
case WM_TIMER:
{
    if (divisible % 15 == 0) {
        KillTimer (hwnd, 1);
        MessageBox (hwnd, "a", "a", MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE | MB_ICONASTERISK);
        SetTimer (hwnd, 1, 50, NULL);
    }
    divisible++;
    break;
}
```

But you should debug this before you change the code, so that you fully understand what's going on.

Comment: "*One way to resolve this is to ...*"- another option is to set a flag when calling `MessageBox()` and clear the flag upon exit, then have your `WM_TIMER` handier simply don't do anything at all if the flag is set.

Comment: A far better option is to not introduce intrusive debugging code at all. Visual Studio allows you to set [trace points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints#BKMK_Print_to_the_Output_window_with_tracepoints), that can write any message to the Debug Output (including the value of objects), without ever suspending execution. Or changing code.